# How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^n i.i! = (n+1)!-1$ with mathematical induction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction

I'm trying to prove 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i.i! = (n+1)!-1
$$
with mathematical induction. The first step I did after prove it for 1 was:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i.i! = (n+2)!-1= (n+2).(n+1)!-1
$$
but I can't do anything more.

Comment: The answer by mfl at the duplicate is by induction.

Comment: @DietrichBurde how can I find my similar question here when I don't have any keyword? just like this question?

Comment: You were almost there btw, $$([n+1]+1)!-1$$ was what you had to split it into to prove it holds for $n+1$

Comment: @DietrichBurde, you can also try using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) to search for similar questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality is trivial for $n=1.$ Assume it is true for $n,$ then 
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i\cdot i!&=\sum_{i=1}^n i.i!+(n+1).(n+1)!\\&=(n+1)!-1+(n+1)(n+1)! \qquad \text{(induction hypothesis)}\\ 
&=(n+2)(n+1)!-1\\&=(n+2)!-1.\end{align*}$$